# List or dictionary of two key tuple

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a set of two-key pairs of strings { (a1, b1), (a2, b2), (a3, b3), ... }. In my scenario (a1, b1) == (b1, a1), so a (a1, b1) or (b1, a1) combination should be part of my set only once.

In a C# application I need to be able to:

- Add a new pairs of these (a,b) tuples
- Efficiently (i.e. fast) check if a pair of (a1, b1) or (b1, a1) is already in my table.

How would you implement something like this, with a Dictionary[Tuple[K1, K2]], or something else? If using a Dictionary, is there any way to tell it to consider (K1,K2) the same as (K2, K1) so I wouldn't have to add both combinations? Or maybe adding both (K1, K2) and (K2, K1) is the way to go?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently I can't type lt or gt characters, they don't get escaped, so I replaced those with brackets / parentheses

Comment: What do you need to do with the set? How would you want to look values up, for example?

Comment: @JonSkeet I just need to quickly check that (a1,b1) and (b1, a1) are already in the set. I'm dealing with a large number of these things, so it needs to be fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a storage class exposing Add(a, b) and similar functions. The internal storage can be a `HashSet<T>` where T is a suitable string-tuple key. The only thing important about this Key and comparer is to use hash and equality functions that are symmetric, i.e. that (a,b) equals (b,a), and consequently that hash(a,b) == hash(b,a).

As pointed out earlier, a lot of hash functions has this property, for example sums and xor of the hash values. I chose to not use xor because it means that all pairs of equal strings would have hash zero, which probably could lead to inefficient lookup if pairs of equal strings are likely.

The below implementation assumes all strings are non null, but has no error checking.

```
public class Storage
{
   private HashSet<Key> set;

   public Storage()
   {
      set = new HashSet<Key>(new Key.Comparer());
   }

   public void Add(string a, string b)
   {
      set.Add(new Key{A=a, B=b});
   }

   public bool Contains(string a, string b)
   {
      return set.Contains(new Key{A=a, B=b});
   }

   internal class Key
   {
       internal String A { get; set; }
       internal String B { get; set; }
       internal class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Key>
       {
          public bool Equals(Key x, Key y)
          {
             return (x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B) || (x.A == y.B && x.B == y.A);
          }
          public int GetHashCode(Key k)
          {
             int aHash = k.A.GetHashCode();
             int bHash = k.B.GetHashCode();
             // Hash for (x,y) same as hash for (y,x)
             if (aHash > bHash)
                return bHash * 37 + aHash;
             return aHash * 37 + bHash;
          }
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: An old habit of always combining hashes like "a*prime_number + b". It is the usual simple pattern when combining hash codes to avoid collisions, but I'm actually unsure if it is strictly necessary when doing a symmetric hash like this now that I think about it. It may be that it creates asymmetry between a,b that wouldn't be there if I only summed the hashes. Someone can perhaps fill in here, its late...

Comment: When aHash and bHash are hashes, why don't you simply XOR them together? Would that be bad?

Comment: It would be bad in case one often adds tuples of equal strings since ALL such tuples get the same hash (zero).

Answer (score 6):

Make a custom class that implements [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) (and make sure to properly override `GetHashCode`).  You can then use this in a `HashSet<T>`, and the two pairs can be made "equal" automatically.

Comment: And that would properly "index" the items? I'm trying to prevent a "scan", i.e. calling of "equals" for every item check.

Comment: @pbz: So long as you've got a sensible hash code, that should be fine.

Comment: What should the GetHashCode look like? key1+key2 or key2+key1?

Comment: @pbz doesn't really matter, as long as `<a,b>` and `<b,a>` produce exactly the same hash code.  A simple addition would work, or an XOR...

Comment: This may be elementary, but I'm obviously missing something. Could you give me an example where a hash for a pair of ("abc", "def") gives the same hash as a pair of ("def", "abc")? Thanks.

Comment: @pbz You can just `return str1.GetHashCode() ^ str2.GetHashCode();`

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework? It looks like a problem from a book.

1. Define class `Key`, define equality and hash operators and methods. (It means you should define method `Equals`, operator `==`, method `GetHashCode`, and possibly other methods if compiler will want them.)
2. Use `HashSet<Key>`.

Comment: No, not a homework problem... I was just trying to explain in a non-vague manner.

Comment: But if I override the Equals method, doesn't that slow down how the items are found in the list? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of fast access? Thanks.

Comment: We can hardly talk about slowdowns here - because you simply need a way to compare two keys. If you don't provide a way to compare keys, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary where the key is generated by a function which  accepts 2 strings and generates the hash like this: compare both strings, build a concated string which is made of the "smaller" string + seperator+ " larger" string. this way order doesn't matter. a similar "equals" operator can also be implemented.

Comment: Yes , using String.Compare(str1,str2)